# Installing TextWrangler command line tools into /usr/bin

Tags: terminal, text-editor

I just installed the text wrangler command line tools and they are placed into `/usr/local/bin` by default.  On Lion this directory appears to be a root only directory, and I don't want to have to run the edit command as root.

However if I copy the edit command into `/usr/local` it won't launch textwrangler. I can see the "edit" process running but text wranger isn't launched.

Is there a trick to getting edit working in `/usr/bin`? The other command line tools from textwrangler work fine from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but `/usr/bin` is still a root/wheel directory, so it is actually going to be worse to install the textwrangler stuff there.

In any case, in your terminal type

`echo $PATH` and see if `/usr/local/bin` is in the path.  If `/usr/local/bin` is in your path all the stuff you install there will NOT need root permissions to be run.  If it is not, you can add it as such:

go to `/etc/paths.d/`

create a text file that you can call localstuff (or whatever)

edit localstuff putting `/usr/local/bin` in it.

Example:

```
$ ls /etc/paths.d/
50-X11   MacGPG2  TeX      TeXbin   git      julia

$ cat /etc/paths.d/julia 
/usr/local/julia

$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/julia:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
```

make sure that your shell is a login shell in whatever terminal you are using, the OSX predicated way of adding stuff to `$PATH` seems to break if you do not use a login shell.

As I said though, chances are that `/usr/local/bin` is in your user's `$PATH` anyway, so no need to worry.  I'd also move all the textwrangler files you put in `/usr/bin` in `/usr/local/bin` to avoid future problems.

Comment: You're right it doesn't need admin permissions to run, I guess at some point I might have changed the permissions on /usr/local/bin changing them back fixed the problem.